# sakuraエディタで・と改行マークの間を表す正規表現を教えてほしい

Tags: 正規表現, サクラエディタ

サクラエディタでの正規表現の表し方を教えて下さい。
・と改行マークの間に何文字か任意の文字があるのですが、
この・から改行マークまでを正規表現で表す方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

・.*\rでいけました。
回答いただいた方、ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

sakuraエディタでの正規表現での表し方を教えてほしい30文字って長いね

`・.+$`

Answer (score 1):

`・[^・]+$`

かも
(30文字以上ないと、投稿を許されないなんて)